# Python Mixed Integer Optimization

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I'm new to mixed integer optimization problem. Currently, I'm using pulp python interface with default CBC solver to solve the problem.
The problem is to improve resource utilization in a cancer clinic model and below is the code with objective function and constraints. When I use prob.solve(), I have 3 different questions:
1. I get values 1.0 for BeginTreatment variable however I do not get values 1.0 for ContinueTreatment variable?
2. Based on chair continuity constraint, slots numbered more than 29 should not be assigned to pat_type of 8 as there are max 40 slots only available. But I still see that? (and not only for pat_type of 8 but others too)
3. Should I try a different solver instead of the default CBC solver of pulp? If yes, how do I do that?

```
import pulp
# Indices and Parameters
chair = list(range(1,24))
pat_type = list(range(1,9))
slot = list(range(1,41))
type_and_demand = {1:24,2:10,3:13,4:9,5:7,6:6,7:2,8:1}
type_and_slots = {1:1,2:4,3:8,4:12,5:16,6:20,7:24,8:28}
# Decision Variables
Y = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("BeginTreatment", 
    (chair,pat_type,slot),0,1,pulp.LpBinary)
X = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("ContinueTreatment", 
    (chair,pat_type,slot),0,1,pulp.LpBinary)
# Objective Function
prob = pulp.LpProblem("ChairUtilization", pulp.LpMaximize)
prob += pulp.lpSum([Y[i][j][t] for i in chair for j in pat_type for t in 
        slot]) 
# Constraints
# Patient Type 1 Continuity constraint
for i in chair:
 for t in slot:
   for j in range(1,2):
        prob += X[i][j][t] == 0
# Chair Continuity Constraint
for i in chair:
 for j in range(2,9):
   for t in range(1,(len(slot)-type_and_slots[j]+1)+1):
    prob += pulp.lpSum([X[i][j][u] for u in range(t+1,t+type_and_slots[j])]) 
            == (type_and_slots[j] - 1)*Y[i][j][t]
# No more than one patient per chair
for t in slot:
 for i in chair:
    prob += pulp.lpSum([X[i][j][t] for j in pat_type]) + pulp.lpSum([Y[i][j] 
            [t] for j in pat_type]) <= 1
 # No new arrivals during lunch time period
 prob += pulp.lpSum([Y[i][j][t] for i in chair for j in pat_type for t in 
         range(19,23)]) == 0
# Patient Mix
for j in pat_type:
 prob += pulp.lpSum([Y[i][j][t] for i in chair for t in slot]) == 
         type_and_demand[j]
prob.solve()
```

Comment: Hey there Mixit! Glad to see you join the SO community. However, the goal of this website is not to dump code and jargon on other users, but to ask questions useful to future visitors of the site

Comment: Can you reduce the question down to a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the problem you seek to have a resolution to?

Comment: I want to maximize my objective function which is chair utilization along with constraints described as comments in python code. However, I'm facing anomalies, which I described in the questions. Let me know, if you are looking for some specifics?

Comment: Unfortunately, as you've phrased the question, this question is not appropriate for this website. If you have a more specific question, post that, otherwise I'd recommend looking at a different source for help.

Comment: Just remember that none of us get paid for this

Comment: Reduce the size of the data and print the model `prob`. That will allow you to see the individual constraints. Changing solvers will not help you: you are missing some constraints.

Comment: I tried reducing the data and printed the model. The result output doesn't seem to follow some constraints, there are anomalies.Also, I have added one more constraint to the above code

Comment: I'm following the paper - https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281843060_Improving_Resource_Utilization_in_a_Cancer_Clinic_An_Optimization_Model